# What rule has been used in this integration of the product of a time derivative and function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What rule has been used to get the following equation:

$$\int_0^T {\left( {{{\dot a}_t}{e^{ - \int_0^t {({r_\tau } - n)d\tau } }}} \right)dt}  = \int_0^T {\left( {{a_t}{e^{ - \int_0^t {({r_\tau } - n)d\tau } }}} \right)dt}  - \int_0^T {\left( {{a_t}\left( {{d \over {dt}}{e^{ - \int_0^t {({r_\tau } - n)d\tau } }}} \right)} \right)dt} $$

Simplified a bit, I guess the more general form looks like:

$$\int_0^T {\left( {{{\dot a}_t}{g_t}} \right)dt}  = \int_0^T {\left( {{a_t}{g_t}} \right)dt}  - \int_0^T {\left( {{a_t}{{\dot g}_t}} \right)dt} $$

Where
$$\matrix{  { {\dot a_t} = {da_t \over {dt}} = {da(t) \over {dt}}, } & { {\dot g_t} = {dg_t \over {dt}} = {dg(t) \over {dt}} }  \cr } $$

Comment: That looks wrong to me...unless $\frac d{dt}(a_t g_t) = a_t g_t$.

Comment: What exactly stands $a_t$ for? the partial deriviative of $a$ in respect to $t$ ?

Comment: $a_t = a(t)$ is simply a function of time. I edited the question, hopefully it is clearer what $a_t$ stands for now, and what is the partial derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called ''integration by parts'' and the correct form would be:
\begin{gather}
\int_0^T \left[\frac{d}{dt}a(t)\right] g(t) dt =  a(t)g(t)\bigg|_0^T - \int_0^T a(t)\left[\frac{d}{dt} g(t)\right] dt.
\end{gather}

You can derive it by using the product rule backwards, i.e. 
$$\frac{d}{dx} (u(x)v(x)) = u'(x)v(x) + u(x)v'(x).$$